# Python script to retrieve files from a server to a local drive

Tags: python, gis, arcgis, arcmap

I'm new here, and a rookie when it comes to Python. I work in the GIS field and would like to run a script which takes all of the files (about 10) in a specific folder on a server, and copy them to a local external hard drive.

These files on the server are updated daily, so I'd like for the script to allow the files in my local drive to be updated as well (essentially replacing the old files).

Is this complicated? Any help at all is appreciated...

Thanks

Comment: what protocol do you use for accessing the files on the server - HTTP, SSH, FTP, etc?

Comment: I guess you describe the following scenario: ``SERVER <> INTERNET <> YOUR DESKTOP (EXTERNAL HARD DRIVE)``? What kind of access to the server-files do you have?

Comment: After some reading I suppose the best way to go about this may be a .bat file? These files are simply located on a network drive which I have full access too. I would just like to have them automatically save to my external hard drive.

Comment: Oh!? Windows? Sorry, can't help you there, but i guess a batch-script would be a possibility. in python you could consider something aka: ``open(local_file, 'w').write(urllib2.urlopen(file_location).read())`` as a quick and dirty approach.

Comment: Thanks for the help and concern folks! I created a batch file which has done the trick... Sorry for any confusion, as I'm fairly new to the programming world.

Answer (score 1):

Use xcopy -

To copy all the files and subdirectories (including any empty subdirectories) from drive A to drive B, type:
xcopy a: b: /s /e

http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/xcopy.mspx?mfr=true

If you need to copy feature classes or other geodatabase objects you can export any ArcToolBox tool to a python script to automate it.